# Remix: file download

Tags: remix.run

I want to allow my users to download a text file.

How would I go about this in Remix?

I tried exposing the txt file via a resource route, but then the user navigates away from the page. But I'd the file to just download, or maybe have them pick a download location. In any case, I want the user to stay on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to figure out how to do this for an app that I am building.

In short, you will need to set `Content-Disposition` header to "attachment". This forces the download.

Then you will to construct a response that streams the document that you want to be dowloaded.

Here is an end to end example:

```
import { createReadableStreamFromReadable } from '@remix-run/node';
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';

export const loader = async () => {
  const file = createReadableStreamFromReadable(
    Readable.from(['Hello, World!']),
  );

  return new Response(file, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="hello.md"',
      'Content-Type': 'text/markdown',
    },
  });
};
```

Here I use `Readable.from(['Hello, World!'])` to construct the file, but this could be `fs.readFile`, etc.

You place all of this in a `_route.ts` of your choice.

When linking to this resource route from the app, you will need to add [`reloadDocument` attribute](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/components/link#reloaddocument) to the link, e.g.

```
<Link to="/download" reloadDocument />
```

This forces the use of browser navigation instead of client-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard `a` tag, you can trigger a download if you add the `download` attribute to it => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

You can then link to the resource route that produces the txt file and the download should work as expected.

Maybe this even works with the Remix/ReactRouter `Link` component, but I’m just on the phone currently so cannot test this. Anyways, a standard anchor tag should work.